# Is there a method in PowerAutomate Adobe PDF Services Connector to order files by name before merging?

Tags: pdf, merge, alphabetical-sort, power-automate-custom-connector

I've written (with the help of friendly StackOverflowers) a recursive flow within MS PowerAutomate (web) using the Merge action of the Adobe PDF Services Connector which, merges all .pdf files in any folder into a single .pdf file. Currently the software my client is working with outputs multi page reports in individual 1 page .pdfs within a single folder, no idea why????

This works perfectly but now I've run into another problem. The connector merge action seems to be merging in alphabetical order, rather than numerical (or processed) order. I'm getting the pages in the following order:

Page 1
Page 10
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4 etc.

Even if I rename the files by just number, I'm sure I'll get the same issue. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any hints?

I'm honestly not sure what to try! I'm a bit stumped.